# Configure hibernate 4.x to use Elasticache with Redis as 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

Has anyone been able to configure this? Do you have any tutorials or know what is the configuration and which jars I need?

Answer (score 0):

Use [hibernate-redis](https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis) it built on top of [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework which supports AWS Elasticache